# Laravel Eloquent Query Using WHERE with AND orWhere

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. In use in my project Laravel 5.8.
I have this array:

```
array:4 [
  0 => 1
  1 => 3
  2 => 4
  3 => 5
]
```

and function:

```
public function getPaymentMethods(array $paymentId)
    {
            dd($paymentId);
            return PaymentSettings::where('id', '=', $paymentId)->get();
    }
```

It's not working because in $paymentId I have array.
How can I change my code function to use with array (many where/orWhere)?

I need something like this (but in laravel eloquent):

```
SELECT * from payment_settings where id = 1 or id = 3 or id = 4 or id = 5.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `whereIn`,

```
return PaymentSettings::whereIn('id', $paymentId)->get();
```

> **Note:** The whereIn method verifies that a given column's value is contained
>   within the given array:

You can see detailed documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses).

Answer (score 0):

`where` clause is not used to searche from array, `whereIn` is used.
Usage -

```
return PaymentSettings::whereIn('id', $paymentId)->get();
```